# C#.Net automatic resource file designer code generation

Tags: c#, file, resources

In C#.Net when we create a resource file .... Visual Studio generates the designer code for the file automatically. By default the ResourceManager class gets instantiated using the default namespace of the project.
Example

```
[global::System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(global::System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
        internal static global::System.Resources.ResourceManager ResourceManager {
            get {
                if (object.ReferenceEquals(resourceMan, null)) {
                    global::System.Resources.ResourceManager temp = new global::System.Resources.ResourceManager("ISC.Core.UI.DeployResources", typeof(DeployResources).Assembly);
                    resourceMan = temp;
                }
                return resourceMan;
            }
        }
```

I want this resource file to be under a custom namespace (say Custom.Default.DeployResources) and not in the default namespace of the project (which in this case is "ISC.Core.UI.DeployResources")
Is there a way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on your resx, and type your namespace in Custom Tool Namespace.

You can also change the access modifier from internal to public(at the top of your resx when opened in designer) and put your resources in an external assembly.

Answer (score 1):

Could you create a separate project with that default namespace, specifically for resources?

Comment: I had considered this solution ... however I did not want to the resource file to be in a separate assembly....but yes this could be a solution....